# Sort List<> orderby list<string> count

Tags: c#

I have a list like this

```
List<Category> list = Category.getCategoryList();
```

In Category class I have `public List<string> subCat { get; set; }`, Some categories have subCat and some doesn't have, I want to order my list by subCat. where the categories with subCat comes first.
I know that this will sort by catName

```
List<Category> SortedList = list.OrderBy(o => o.catName).ToList();
```

How can I sort by subCat where there is subCat in the list.
Any help would be appricaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by the count of the subcategories so you will have first the categories with more children:

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(o => o.subCat != null ? o.subCat.Count : 0).ToList();
```

If you want to order by category name AND first show the categories with subcategories you can use `ThenBy`:

```
var sorted = list
                .OrderBy(o => o.subCat != null && o.subCat.Count > 0 ? 0 : 1)
                .ThenBy(o => o.catName)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by the existence of sub-categories use for the ordering predicate the `Any` method:

```
//will order by the boolean value - due to the descending first the "true" and then "false"
var result = OrderByDescending(item => item.SubCat.Any());
```

If you want to order by the amount of sum categories:

```
var result = OrderByDescending(item => item.SubCat.Count());
```

For ordering by several properties use `ThenBy`.